# Prevent handling Ctrl+C\V in Lotus Notes database or view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

We have a view which gives users an ability to work with documents where we made our own logic for copying documents. It is accessed with a special button on the view. But the standard behavior of copy paste key shortcuts is still there and some users are using it instead and this is breaking some of our logic.

Is there any way to prevent users to copy \ paste documents within Lotus database or at least a certain view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If the user don't have author/editor/depositor access they can't paste documents into the database.
You also have the QueryPaste event in the view, you can use that to prevent documents from being pasted in.
In Notes 8.0.2 you also got a new database property (under the advanced tab) called "disable export of view data". You can use that one as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a 'disable copy' system field you can apply to any document. If the document contains a field called **$KeepPrivate** with a value of **"1"** then document copying is prevented in the client UI. It prevents copying to the clipboard and printing out. It doesn't prevent screen-print of course. It doesn't prevent pasting in either (see paste agents to control that). Readers cannot paste in a document or edit existing data too. You can set/clear $KeepPrivate as needed and $Readers too if necessary.